# Fetch only returns placeholders, how to make it wait?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Using `fetch` I'm getting the document from my URL with various `<placeholder>` elements that are then loaded via JS (when one retrieves the page normally).

Is there a way to tell fetch to only return the page after that JS has executed?
Or is there way to ask fetch to only return the page after 1 second?

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of the code you're using?

Comment: `fetch` will return you the HTML, it will ***not*** run any accompanying code. If you expect formatted template, you should either return it from the back-end, or format it separately on the front-end.

Comment: To expand on what @VLAZ already said: When you load a page in a browser, the browser requests the HTML and then does a bunch of other stuff: parsing, rendering, fetching referenced resources and scripts, executing those scripts, etc… Your `fetch` call is the "requests the HTML" part. None of that other stuff is going to happen.

Comment: The quickest way to fix your approach: set the loaded HTML as `.innerHTML` of a newly created container div; this will parse it into a DOM. Then populate it using code in an already loaded script (move it there if necessary) and insert the final, populated HTML into your document.